# Cannot properly link ZSTD library when building GCC 10

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to build GCC 10 from source in Ubuntu 20.04, and I have built the other dependencies. Below is the the flags I have set to configure the make files:

```
$PWD/../gcc/configure \
--with-gmp=/tmp/gcc \
--with-mpfr=/tmp/gcc \
--with-mpc=/tmp/gcc \
--with-zstd=/../zstd
```

where gmp, mpfr, and mpc are in /tmp/gcc. I cannot build zstd in /tmp/gcc as there is no configure file for it. When I tried to run the command `make -j8`, this is the output I get:

```
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:120: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_maxCLevel'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:121: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_maxCLevel'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:135: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_compressBound'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:138: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_compress'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:141: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_isError'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:142: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_getErrorName'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:161: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_getFrameContentSize'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:168: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_decompress'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:170: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_isError'
$PWD/../gcc/gcc/lto-compress.c:171: error: undefined reference to 'ZSTD_getErrorName'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have already tried too obtain ZSTD from `sudo apt-get install zstd` and updated my PATH, but nothing has happened. What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: /../zstd is not a valid path. Do you perhaps mean --with-zstd=../zstd (for /tmp/zstd/)?

Comment: Or rather, /../zstd is a valid path. It is equivalent to /zstd.

Comment: I checked the configure file and there is no flag called --with-zstd= for some reason. Also, /../zstd is not a equivalent to /zstd because I'm in a different directory called gcc-build. I built zstd in a folder called zstd that is located in /../zstd, and the binaries are there, but it still can't see it. Because of this, I realized that I need to be able to link the libraries somehow.